# adding Doxygen plugin to qtcreator in linux

Tags: linux, qt-creator, doxygen

I want to add Doxygen plugin to QtCreator. 
I am using QtCreator 2.5.2 in ubuntu 12.10 and the latest Doxygen version for QT is 2.4.0. 
I've changed the doxygen.pluginspec file to get rid of version error. 
But now I've got another error: 
can not load library libdoxygen.so (libQtconcurrent.so can not open shared object file:No such file or directory)
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are no longer stuck, but if not, I will still try to help.

Yes, the quick install binaries are available only for QtCreator 2.4, but the plugin stays easy to install without it : you have to download the sources and build them yourself, as written [in the wiki](http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/wiki#Compilation-from-sources).

Moreover, you have to build it with the same version of Qt4 as the one that was used for build your QtCreator (have a look [here](http://dev.kofee.org/boards/1/topics/41))
It became compatible with QtCreator 2.7 and Qt5 at the end of March, and I succeeded in installing in in QtCreator2.8-beta.
If you have any other question, I guess it would be better to ask them in the plugin forum where developpers always answer to people in need.

Hope this helps (you and other people in need).

Answer (score 0):

You can install Doxywizard wich provides an user interface to use Doxygen.

I'm not shure I'm using fedora to install I used.

yum install doxygen-doxywizard.x86_64.

For Ubuntu it should be if the package name is the same.

apt-get install doxygen-doxywizard.x86_64

(as root)